# Problema ao usar @JsonIgnore Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, jpa, spring-boot

Tenho uma relação @ManyToOne entre Mangas e Autor, onde Muitos Mangas pode ter um Autor  e um Autor pode ter muitos Mangas.

Gostaria de listar todos os Mangas com cada Autor, e quando pesquisar pelo Autor, traga uma lista com todos os mangas que o Autor criou.

Usando @JsonIgnore na tabela Autor, quando faço GET na tabela Mangas, ela retorna Todos os Mangas com cada autor, porem na tabela Autor, se fizer GET não retorna cada Manga do Autor. Removendo o @JsonIgnore, fica em um loop até dar erro.

Mangas:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Mangas")
public class MangasEntity {


    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private  Status status;
    private Date dataLancado;   
    private AutorEntity autor;

    @ManyToOne  
    @JoinTable(name="mangas_autor",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="manga_id",referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = 
    @JoinColumn(name="autor_id",referencedColumnName="id"))
    public AutorEntity getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }
```

Autor

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Autor")
    public class AutorEntity {

    private Long id;
    private String nome;    
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<MangasEntity> manga;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="autor",targetEntity= MangasEntity.class,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)    
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL,CascadeType.DELETE})
    public Set<MangasEntity> getManga() {
        return manga;
    }
```

AutorRepository

```
public interface AutorRepository extends JpaRepository<AutorEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT  a.id, a.nome FROM AutorEntity a  ") //Busca id e nome do Autor
    List<AutorEntity> buscarAutores();

    @Query("Select a FROM AutorEntity a") // Deve retornar cada Autor com seus mangas
    public List<AutorEntity> buscarAutorEMangas();
```

[Resultado da consulta na tabela Mangas](https://i.imgur.com/hHbsDCK.png)

Erro ao consultar Mangas sem o @JsonIgnore na tabela Autor.

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
```

Comment: A solução será a mesma? Obrigado.

Comment: Eu estava com o mesmo problema, isso resolveu.

Comment: Eu mudei para Unidirecional a tabela Mangas, @ManyToOne Mangas para Autor, e funcionou normal, agora estou com problemas no JPQL, está trazendo Mangas Repetidos.[O JPQL quero consultar o AUTOR e Concatenar os mangas, já usei CONCAT e nada](https://i.imgur.com/jLR07Fe.png), [Retorna Valores repetidos](https://i.imgur.com/dFqY8eR.png), [Essa é a consulta no MYSQL](https://i.imgur.com/exrEkUV.png)

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Encontrei outro modo de resolver esse problema sobre recursão, usei  @ JsonIgnoreProperties na Entidade Mangas e Autor.[Get Manga e Autor](https://i.imgur.com/8h5HNDn.jpg)